# map() with partial arguments: save up space

Tags: python, python-3.x, functional-programming, python-multiprocessing

I have a very large list of dictionaries, which keys are a triple of (`string`, `float`, `string`) and whose values are again lists.
`cols_to_aggr` is basically a `list(defaultdict(list))`

I wish I could pass to my function `_compute_aggregation` not only the list index `i` but also exclusively the data contained by that index, namely `cols_to_aggr[i]` instead of the whole data structure `cols_to_aggr` and having to get the smaller chunk inside my parallelized functions.
This because the problem is that this passing of the whole data structures cause my Pool to eat up all my memory with no efficiency at all.

```
with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=n_workers, maxtasksperchild=500) as pool:
    results = pool.map(
        partial(_compute_aggregation, cols_to_aggr=cols_to_aggr,
                aggregations=aggregations, pivot_ladetag_pos=pivot_ladetag_pos,
                to_ix=to_ix), cols_to_aggr)

def _compute_aggregation(index, cols_to_aggr, aggregations, pivot_ladetag_pos, to_ix):
    data_to_process = cols_to_aggr[index]
```

To give a patch to my memory issue I tried to set a `maxtasksperchild` but without success, I have no clue how to optimally set it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`dict.values()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items), you can iterate over the values of a dictionary.

So you could change your code to:

```py
with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=n_workers, maxtasksperchild=500) as pool:
    results = pool.map(
        partial(_compute_aggregation,
                aggregations=aggregations, pivot_ladetag_pos=pivot_ladetag_pos,
                to_ix=to_ix), cols_to_aggr.values())

def _compute_aggregation(value, aggregations, pivot_ladetag_pos, to_ix):
    data_to_process = value
```

If you still need the keys in your `_compute_aggregation` function, use [`dict.items()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) instead.

Comment: Hi @pypae, thank you for your answer. I am confused by one thing: `cols_to_aggr` is an object like this `list(defaultdict(list))` - so I cannot directly apply to it a dict method, isn't it?
That you mentioned I could do it if I had a `defaultdict(list)` or am I wrong?

Comment: True, I got that wrong, sorry. But if `cols_to_aggr` is a list of `defaultdict`, then `index` should already be the `defaultdict` right?

Comment: True, but actually you even gave me an idea earlier and I got rid of the first `list` surface and adapted :) 
Thank you!
You can update your answer by including also `index` for the `list` case, such that if someone pass by is not misled :)